# Vacuum Pump Oil Contamination

Tags: vacuum-pumps

I have a [vacuum pump](https://www.buschvacuum.com/us/en/products/r5-kb-0020-0040-d-f.html) that has water in the packing oil. This oil is function as a lubricant and sealant. I have changed the oil 2 times now and it still shows signs of contamination. Is this a telling sign that the whole pump needs to be rebuilt? The machine works fine but from a reliability view should should there be a plan to overhaul the pump or not? Since this is a production machine I want to keep it running as long as possible. I am debating on changing the oil every week to keep the machine up. One of the more senior men says that in higher humidity the pump pulls moisture from the air and that when the humidity is lower change the oil.

Comment: If the oil is indeed helping seal, your senior man is correct that the moisture is likely from air.  You can increase air's capability to carry water via increased temperature and reduction in pressure. That way you are not tied to the weather.

Comment: That is what I thought. I just wanted to verify via 3rd party since there are a lot of opinions going around. Could you please make your comment into an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: you should contact the manufacturer

Comment: @TigerGuy Thanks for the comment but that has already been done.